# GridviewAdapter - first element individual (not in array)

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have an array like: String[] values = {"val1", "val2", "val3"}

Now I put this Values into my Gridview.
Everything is fine until this point.

But now I'm trying to add one specific value to this gridview. This should be the first value of my Gridview and should not influence the position of the other values in my String[].

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview_textview);
      textView.setText(values[position]);
};
```

In this function I set the values!
I also tried it with a boolean to check, if this is the first element, but this influences the position. In this case, it just overrides the "val1"

Comment: The static value that you are trying to add, is it also a String type?

Comment: right - same type. For example, I want to add "back".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is going to be using a separate array (or even `ArrayList<String>`) as your data set in the adapter. Then however you are setting your data set in the adapter, instead of just providing `values` you could do something like this:

```
String[] values = new String[] {"val1", "val2", "val3"};
ArrayList<String> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
dataset.add("back");
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    dataset.add(values[i]);
}
//provide dataset to adapter
```

**Edit #1**

If you are using multiple data types in a single adapter, an approach I like to use is an using an `ArrayList<Object>`, or some other common super class of the data types you are working with. If you aren't using a certain class for your button, you could create a ViewModel class for the button, lets `BlackButtonViewModel`.

Then when setting up your dataset you can do something like:

```
List<Article> articles = ...
List<Object> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
dataset.add(new BlackButtonViewModel());
dataset.addAll(articles);
```

Then in your adapter when creating your views you could do something like this:

```
private enum ItemViewType {
    BlackButton(1), Article(2);

    private int id;

    ItemViewType(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class BlackButtonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    BlackButtonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == ItemViewType.BlackButton.getId()) {
        View v = ...inflate black button layout
        return new BlackButtonViewHolder(v);
    } else if (viewType == ItemViewType.Article.getId()) {
        View v = ...inflate article layout
        return new ArticleViewHolder(v);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object item = dataset.get(position);
    if(item instanceof BlackButtonViewModel) {
       return ItemViewType.BlackButton.getId();
    } else if(item instanceof Article) {
       return ItemViewType.Article.getId();
    }
}

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(holder instanceof BlackButtonViewHolder) {
       BlackButtonViewModel model = (BlackButtonViewModel) dataset.get(position);
       ...set up black button view contents
    } else if (holder instanceof ArticleViewHolder) {
       Article article = (Article) dataset.get(position);
       ...set up article view contents
    }
}
```

Comment: good approach, but in my running system I have an object called "Articles". 
So its an ArrayList<Articles>. The first element in my gridview, should not be an article.
This first element it just beeing used as a back-button.

Comment: @MaximilianZelles updated answer. This should do what you are looking for.